# Python - Substitute a variable in another variable

Tags: python

I have a function that checks the status of a cluster but running a command on a remote server.
In order to get the status, I need to provide a cluster password which I get from another function.

My code is ::

```
def clusterHealthCheck(redisIp, loadBalancerIp):
    password = file_utils.getPasswd("password.txt", "REDIS_PASS")
    result = shell_utils.runCommandOnRemoteHost(redisIp, "redis-cli -a 'password' info replication | grep slave0 | cut -d'=' -f4 | cut -d',' -f1")
```

My `getPasswd` function gets the password from a file and saves it to a variable.
My `runCommandOnRemoteHost` function runs a shell command (2nd argument) on the remote server. This second arguments needs the password which comes from my first variable.

So I need to substitute one variable into another.

This is my second variable `"redis-cli -a 'password' info replication | grep slave0 | cut -d'=' -f4 | cut -d',' -f1"` which needs `password` substituted in it.

Is it possible to do this ? I tried escaping characters but it does not work.

Comment: sounds like you want to concatenate the string before `'password'` with the password and then the string after `'password'`... so in theory `"stuff before password" + password + "stuff after password"` should be the string you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
def clusterHealthCheck(redisIp, loadBalancerIp):
    password = file_utils.getPasswd("password.txt", "REDIS_PASS")
    result = shell_utils.runCommandOnRemoteHost(redisIp, "redis-cli -a '%s' info replication | grep slave0 | cut -d'=' -f4 | cut -d',' -f1" %password)
```

This did the trick for me.